# mysql search query search many columns

Tags: mysql

I have a search problem in MySql.

I need to search "zipcode", "number of people" and here is the tricky part I also need to search more "date" / columns.

Here is the code so far :)

```
 $sqlsearch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE zipcode LIKE '%$ziprangesub%' AND numberofpeople>='$numberofpeople' AND '$date' in ('date1','date2','date3','date4')");
```

The database is like:

zipcode | numberofpeople | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4

So I need that people can search the database where zipcode is exact and numberofpeople is equal or less then and date match one of the 4 date.

I can do it with one date with: AND '$date'=date1 but not all 4 columns

Thx, 
Christian from Denmark

Comment: Please be aware that Mysql_connect is deprecated and no longer supported - [Please consider using MySQLi or PDO.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$sqlsearch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE zipcode LIKE '%$ziprangesub%' AND numberofpeople>='$numberofpeople' AND '$date' in (date1,date2,date3,date4)");
```

Is it giving any error?

Comment: God I think that it's working now :) Just without ''.

Thank you so much dcp1986 you just save my day :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know php, but seems to me you are using the value as the column, try this maybe?

```
 $sqlsearch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE zipcode LIKE '%$ziprangesub%' AND numberofpeople>='$numberofpeople' AND (date1='$date' OR date2='$date' OR date3='$date' OR date4='$date')");
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kay for your answer :)
It worked with dcp1986 answer. Have a good day :)